# Proper use of Lwt_main.run()

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt, lwt

I have encountered some errors when using `Lwt_main.run()`. Basically I have two infinite loops with type `unit -> 'a Lwt.t = <fun>` and when I start both loops I receive errors. I am using these in the context that one loop is a writer loop and the other is a reader loop. Basically I have to update some data with the writer much more often than I use it with the reader. The errors I receive can be illustrated with the code below.

```
let rec p1 () =
Lwt_io.print "1\n"
>>= fun () -> Lwt_unix.sleep 1.0
>>= p1
;;

val p1 : unit -> 'a Lwt.t = <fun>

let rec p5 () =
Lwt_io.print "5\n"
>>= fun () -> Lwt_unix.sleep 5.0
>>= p5
;;

val p5 : unit -> 'a Lwt.t = <fun>

Lwt_main.run(p1(); p5());;

Characters 13-17:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
Characters 13-17:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

I can run the Lwt_main.run statements as follows without errors but it seems that this solution is just masking the warning with the wildcard instead of fixing the warning.

```
let _ = Lwt_main.run(p1())
let _ = Lwt_main.run(p5())
```

What is the proper use of `Lwt_main.run()` in this context so that I can fix the errors instead of just masking them with the wildcard character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it is not an error, but warning. It states that expression that is terminated with `;` doesn't evaluate to a value of type `unit` as expected. In your case you have two expressions `p1 ()` that evaluates to `unit Lwt.t` and `p5 ()` that evaluates to the same type. Obviously they do not have type `unit`, so that you can't put `;` after `p1 ()` or `p5 ()`. Since both of them are lwt threads, and what you want (I suspect) is to run them in parallel, then you need to use `Lwt.pick` function, or its infix equivalent `<&>`:

```
let () = Lwt_main.run (p1 () <&> p5 ())
```

On the other hand, if you want to serialize this threads, i.e., to run one after another, not in parallel, then you need to bind them using `>>=` operation, or, if you have enabled syntax support, then you can use `>>` syntax, thats actually stands for monadic semicolon.